# On Duplicate Key INSERT (rather than UPDATE)

Tags: mysql

Why wouldn't MySQL have this feature?

```
INSERT INTO abc (a) VALUES ('bla')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
 INSERT INTO ...
```

Do I need a stored procedure to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert into where exactly? The same table? You already *know* that's impossible because the primary key already exists.

If you're talking about inserting the row into a *different* table, that's another thing altogether, not to be done with a single insert statement. That's because the general idea of the `insert` statement is to get a specific row into a specific table. That can usually be done with "instead-of"-type triggers.

That idea also means that you probably shouldn't try to use a single `insert` statement to insert a *different* row (such as changing the primary key) in the case where the original already exists. In that case, the primary key is almost certainly an artificial one in which case an auto-increment key would probably be the way to go.

The idea behind the `insert ... on duplicate key update` is get that row in whether it exists already or not. It *does* get a specific row into a specific table.

Comment: into different table, I am trying to use queries to handle logic: if record exists then insert into many-to-many table

Comment: @amiawizard: the _relationship_ is either one-to-one or it's not, this doesn't change depending on how many references there currently are between a source row and destination rows. I would suggest _making_ it properly many-to-many to start with.